# Check if number is of Integer type

Tags: delphi

I want to be able to check if a number (initially Integer) after an operation would fit into Integer again, and if it does not, either jump to an exception or maybe there is some function that does it, like *if isInteger() then ...*

**I do not want to convert to String and then to Integer and checking the length.**

Why I need it? There is a variable (Integer) that keeps update interval, which is doubled every time the request to server fails (no network, whatever). So I want to turn off automatic updates when interval reaches the maximum possible Integer value, which is 2,147,483,647

Ive look for possible answers and it seems that everywhere people use String datatype to check for some conditions on the number, but i do not want to use intermediate datatypes

Comment: Just leave the number as it is if it's greater than 0.5 *  2,147,483,647

Comment: `if (number <= (maxInt div 2)) then number := 2*number;`

Comment: I rolled back your question. Please don't add answers to the question. In fact the *answer* that you added used floating point arithmetic which is just not needed here at all. Don't do that!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that was an impulsive decision.

Comment: A less tedious (but perhaps a flashy C way not available in Delphi) is to check the most significant bit. If it's 1 then don't double, else use a bitshift operation to perform the doubling. Endianness might cause you too much of a headache though for this to be a realistic approach.

Comment: @Bathsheba, msb is the sign, so you have to check the bit before that. Doable in Delphi, but brings only confusion to the code.

Comment: @Bathsheba If you are going to do that it's easiest just to transform the entire problem with log2

Comment: @David Heffernan; I'd be worried about (i) performance and (ii) precision with `log2`. But your answer is the best IMO so +1: my flashy C-like approach does get you in deep water with sign bits, endianness, readability (is it a approach normal in Delphi?) etc.

Comment: @Bathsheba You don't actually ever call log2. You set the counter to 1 and instead of doubling, increment it by 1. When you need the interval you write `1 shl count`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to attempt here to describe a variety of ways to solve your specific problem, and some more general problems of this nature.

---

The most general way to deal with overflow is to let the compiler write the code for you. Enable the [overflow checking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overflow_checking_%28Delphi%29) option and an exception will be raised if you perform an operation whose result does not fit into the data type range.

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Overflow_checking_%28Delphi%29):

> The $Q directive controls the generation of overflow checking code. In the {$Q+} state, certain integer arithmetic operations (+, -, *, Abs, Sqr, Succ, Pred, Inc, and Dec) are checked for overflow. The code for each of these integer arithmetic operations is followed by additional code that verifies that the result is within the supported range. If an overflow check fails, an EIntOverflow exception is raised (or the program is terminated if exception handling is not enabled).

So if you wish to trap such a condition you can enable overflow checking and catch the `EIntOverflow` exception.

---

That will work in full generality. However let us consider a more specific scenario. Suppose that you have a positive integer that you are incrementing by a positive value. Let us say your counter is `count`, and your increment is `incr`. You are trying to detect when

```
count + incr > MaxInt
```

Rearrange the inequality like this:

```
count > MaxInt - incr
```

You can simply test that inequality before attempting the increment operation.

---

In fact your specific case is even simpler than that. You are doubling the value rather than incrementing using addition. So simply check whether or not

```
count <= MaxInt div 2
```

---

Yet another option would be to take base 2 logarithms of the quantities. This would convert your doubling process into increment by 1. In which case all you are actually doing is counting up to 31! And converting back to a true interval is performed with `1 shl count`.

Comment: This actually is a good idea. And I do not need to check the rest of the code for this, since the rest will be consistent with this solution. But this is rather very global solution. If I forget about the fix, it would take me years to debug if problem araises that would be somehow connected with the fix

Comment: Yeah, about the second solution. After I written the question I have actually thought about this.. That the solution is much simpler than I thought

Comment: Yes the first part of the answer is very general. But then the first part of your question is very general also. I cut the answer to fit the question. And in any case, $Q can be applied locally. The second part of the answer is much more specific.

Answer (score 2):

simply check against MaxInt

```
 if (number>MaxInt)
```

**EDIT** (thanks David)

But, this will only work if `number` (the variable holding your intermediate calculation) is `Int64` or `Float` (or any type that can store such large integer).

Note that if `number` is `Integer`, it will never be above `MaxInt`, so the above comparison is useless as it will be shortcut by the compiler. In that case, you might perform (as David and LU suggested) the comparison **before** the actual value be stored in `number`.

```
if (number <= (MaxInt div 2)) then
```

Comment: The compiler could perfectly well optimise out that `if` statement since it can evaluate it. The result is statically known to be `False`, as you yourself state.

Comment: but number could be Int64 or Float, in that case the evaluation is legit, and the result is valid and valuable, as it provides the solution to the problem (and the answer to OP question)

Comment: Do remember that I wrote my comment to your original version of the answer. It also completely unnecessary to use Int64 or floating point here. It's trivially easy to solve the problem entirely in 32 bit integer arithmetic.